# Opening custom jquery tab with anchor link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I really need some help for jquery tabs. I would like to get to a specific tab via external anchor link (http://www.url.com#content2), the navigation link becomes activated and the correct tab is shown.
Other HTML Page

```
<a href="#b">B Title</a> | <a href="#bb">B Title</a>
```

HTML

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="current"><h4><a href="javascript:void();" data-tab="tab1" title="Title 1">Title 1</a></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="javascript:void();" data-tab="tab2" title="Title 2">Title 2</a></h4></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="border-box group">
        <div id="tab1" class="panel group showing" style="display: block;">
            a
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="panel group" style="display: none;">
            <a id="b">B title A<a><br>
information...... <br><br/>
<a id="bb">B title B<a><br>
information...... <br><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
(function(a){a.fn.yiw_tabs=function(b){var c={tabNav:"ul.tabs",tabDivs:".containers",currentClass:"current"};b&&a.extend(c,b);this.each(function(){var b=a(c.tabNav,this),f=a(c.tabDivs,this),e;f.children("div").hide();e=0<a("li."+c.currentClass+" a",b).length?"#"+a("li."+c.currentClass+" a",b).data("tab"):"#"+a("li:first-child a",b).data("tab");a(e).show().addClass("showing").trigger("yit_tabopened");a("li:first-child a",b).parents("li").addClass(c.currentClass);a("a",b).click(function(){if(!a(this).parents("li").hasClass("current")){var e=
"#"+a(this).data("tab");a(this);a("li."+c.currentClass,b).removeClass(c.currentClass);a(this).parents("li").addClass(c.currentClass);a(".showing",f).fadeOut(200,function(){a(this).removeClass("showing").trigger("yit_tabclosed");a(e).fadeIn(200).addClass("showing").trigger("yit_tabopened")})}return!1})})}})(jQuery);
</script>
```

How can i edit? Thank you for your help.

Comment: minified javascript?!!!

Comment: yes, using in wordpress with shortcode

Comment: my point was.. posting minified js wont help us understand what's really going on. There are ways to figure out but it makes it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery `this.hash;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tab1').show();
 $('.tabs li a.current').addClass('current');
 $('.tabs li a').click(function() {
  var tabDivId = this.hash;          
  
  $('.tabs li a').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $('.panel').hide();
  $(tabDivId).fadeIn();
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
.panel{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><h4><a href="#tab1" data-tab="tab1" title="Title 1">Title 1</a></h4></li>
    <li><h4><a href="#tab2" data-tab="tab2" title="Title 2">Title 2</a></h4></li>
</ul>

<div class="border-box group">
    <div id="tab1" class="panel group showing">
        a
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="panel group">
        b
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you add query plugin in your html?

Comment: yes, i added, tabs it working but external anchor link is still not working.. copy your code and testing in local..

Comment: i want like that .. <a href="#b">link to Title 2</a>. So Tab 2 will be open. eg. <div id="tab2" class="panel group"> b <a id="b">title<a></div>

Answer (score 1):

Replace the href attribute value to the id of the corresponding Tab and use below code...

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="current">
<h4><a data-tab="tab1" title="Title 1" href="#tab1">Title 1</a></h4>
</li>
<li>

<h4><a data-tab="tab2" title="Title 2" href="#tab2">Title 2</a></h4>
</li>

</ul>

<div class="border-box group">
<div id="tab1" class="panel group showing" style="display: block;"> a </div>
<div id="tab2" class="panel group" style="display: none;"> b </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(){
var attr = $(this).attr('href')
$('.tabs li').removeClass('current');

$(this).closest('li').addClass('current');

$('.border-box div').hide();
$(attr).show();

})
```

**css**

```
.border-box div { display:none;}
.showing { display:block;}
```

You can ask if any assistance required..

Comment: thank for your help. but not working external out anchor link

Comment: Do You have any fiddle of what you want ??